# re-initializing awk array created by split

Tags: arrays, awk, split

I'm trying to use split to reverse the order of characters in a string that appears as the second field in a file with many such lines. The command:

```
{
    n=split($2,arr," ");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         s=arr[i] s
}
{ print s }
```

does this for one line. However, the arr array (and n) seem immortal, so that when I embed this code into an awk script to process multiple lines, the output corresponding to the field I want reversed accumulates (and reverses) all previous lines:

```
1_B.pdb
GGTGYPGLKDKDDNEGTKYNKLLNATLIVTDVGNTIRTECPDVNRG
AARS_0001_B.pdb
GGTGYPGLKDKDDNEGTKYNKLLNATLIVTDVGNTIRTECPDVNRGGGTGYPGLKDKDDNEGTKYNKLLNATLIVTDVGNTIRTECPDVNRG
AARS_0002_B.pdb
GLILYDGFLDKRDLEGLKYNDILNRTKDVTDVGNTTRTECPDVNRKGGTGYPGLKDKDDNEGTKYNKLLNATLIVTDVGNTIRTECPDVNRGGGTGYPGLKDKDDNEGTKYNKLLNATLIVTDVGNTIRTECPDVNRG
AARS_0003_B.pdb
DGCSLDGFTDDRDLKGALYNKILNKTLIVTDVGNTTRTEVCEKDRYGLILYDGFLDKRDLEGLKYNDILNRTKDVTDVGNTTRTECPDVNRKGGTGYPGLKDKDDNEGTKYNKLLNATLIVTDVGNTIRTECPDVNRGGGTGYPGLKDKDDNEGTKYNKLLNATLIVTDVGNTIRTECPDVNRG
```

This appears to me to be a problem with re-initialization. I've tried to delete all previous elements of arr[] and to reset n to 0, without any effect. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's not `arr` that's immortal, it's `s` since you never [re-]init it to `""` outside of the loop. `arr` is getting re-inited on every call to `split()`.

Try this:

```
{
    n=split($2,arr,/ /)
    s=""
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         s=arr[i] s
    print s
}
```

The 3rd arg for split(), by the way is a field separator, not a string, and a field separator is a regexp with a couple of extra properties so the correct way to call split with a fixed "string" is using RE delimiters `split($2,arr,/ /)`, not string delimiters `split($2,arr," ")`. It doesn't make a functional difference in this case but it does when the field separator gets more complicated so best to get used to doing it the right way.

Bonus round: you would not need to explicitly re-init `s` if you put that code in a function:

```
function rev(str,     arr,n,s,i) {
    n=split(str,arr,/ /)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         s=arr[i] s
    return s
}
...
{ print rev($2) }
```

Reason left as an exercise :-).